# Underfull when using custom list inside multicol

Tags: spacing, lists

When using custom list

```
\newenvironment{questions}{
    \begin{list}{}{
            \let\makelabel=\questionlabel
            \setlength{\labelwidth}{1.5em}
            \setlength{\labelsep}{0.1em}
            \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth+\labelsep+0.5em}
            \setlength{\itemsep}{\baselineskip}
            \setlength{\listparindent}{1em}
            \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}
            \setlength{\topsep}{0pt}
        } 
    }{ 
    \end{list}
}
```

Inside `multicol` environment I get a warning `Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) detected at line 38`. If I use `enumerate` instead, there is no warnings.

MWE

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}


\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{multicol}

\newcounter{qcounter}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\questionlabel[1]{\refstepcounter{qcounter}%
    \global\let\@currentlabel=\@currentlabel
    \normalfont\bfseries\arabic{qcounter}.#1}

\newenvironment{questions}{
    \begin{list}{}{
            \let\makelabel=\questionlabel
            \setlength{\labelwidth}{1.5em}
            \setlength{\labelsep}{0.1em}
            \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth+\labelsep+0.5em}
            \setlength{\itemsep}{\baselineskip}
            \setlength{\listparindent}{1em}
            \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}
            \setlength{\topsep}{0pt}
        } 
    }{ 
    \end{list}
}

\newcommand{\TT}{\item[]}


\begin{document}

        \begin{multicols}{2}
            \begin{questions}

                \TT Some text

                \TT Some text

                \TT Some text

                \TT Some text

            \end{questions}
        \end{multicols}


\end{document}
```

How can I get rid of this warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a fixed width label but no stretchy glue so every label is infinitely underfull as it can not strtech:

add `\hfill`:

```
\newcommand*\questionlabel[1]{\refstepcounter{qcounter}%
    \global\let\@currentlabel=\@currentlabel
    \normalfont\bfseries\arabic{qcounter}.#1\hfill}
```

[image]